# How to count daily orders for one week that currently we are?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have saved orders on mongodb something like this:

```
_id: 5feb0b6cc0ea5745f8d931e3
...
totalPrice: 2935.02
createdAt:2020-12-25T10:56:44.798+00:00
```

If today is 25/01/2021, I need to count for each day of this week how many orders are made.

Example:

```
25/01/2021: 5 (orders)
26/01/2021: 21 (orders)
27/01/2021: 24 (orders)
...
31/01/2021: 22 (orders)
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you want to do: Given a week of the year, get all results for the week grouped by day.

Then you need to perform an aggregation query:

1. Use `$set` and `$week` to get the the week for every document.
2. Use `$match` to find the desired week of the year.
3. Use `$set` again, to get your date as a string, excluding time values, and selected using only: year-month-day.
4. Group by date using `$sum` to get the total count.
5. Optionally include the names of the fields at output.

Here is code to find the current week, based on the current date:

```
let today = new Date();
let oneJan =  new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1); 
let numberOfDays =  Math.floor((today - oneJan) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
let result = Math.ceil(( today.getDay() + 1 + numberOfDays) / 7);
```

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$set": { "date": { "$week": "$createdAt" }}},
  { "$match": { "date": your_desired_week }},
  { "$set": { "date": {
      "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$createdAt" }}}},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$date", "orders": { "$sum": 1 }}},
  { "$project": { "date": "$_id", "orders": 1, "_id": 0 }}
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tw2NaQqde5p)

Comment: Thank you it works, I just had to find the number of current week

Answer (score 1):

Should be this one:

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: {
        $dateFromParts: {
           'isoWeekYear': { $isoWeekYear: "$createdAt" }, 'isoWeek': { $isoWeek: "$createdAt" }
        }
     }, 
     orders: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
```

Comment: I said daily orders for currently week. This is giving also orders from the past. If today is 25/01/2021 it should count only today orders because new week just started. If today is 31/01/2021 it should result  25/01/2021- 2 orders, ..... 31/01/2021 - 5 orders

Answer (score 1):

Try out with this query.

```
var today = new Date(); 
var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
var firstDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first));
var lastDayWeek = new Date(today.setDate(first + 6));
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
$project: {
    date: {
        $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$createdAt'
        }
    }
}}, {
$match: {
    "date": {
        $lt: lastDayWeek,
        $gt: firstDayWeek
    }
},
{$group:{_id:"$createdAt",count:{$sum:1}}}}])
```